# How to scale all the edges proportionally

Tags: modeling, transforms, proportional-editing

I have a simple mesh and I have extruded the edges and want to scale little outside with all edges proportionally. I have applied scale and rotation and removed doubles. I have tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and changed the pivot to *Individual Origins* but nothing seems to work. What else can I do to make my mesh have an equal or proportional scale?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Constrain the scale to two axis. I think in your case X & Y. So Press "S" SHIFT "Z". Or to extrude Press "E" "S" SHIFT "Z".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> command should do the job here. Don't know why it doesn't? What you can do is extrude the bottom edge loop downwards (<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>), select the extruded face loop, press <kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>RMB</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> (to enable *even thickness* mode). Finally delete the unnecessary geometry.
[image]

***Note:*** After doing this the edges lenghts are still not perfect. It's because the model you provided isn't perfect too.
[image]

Comment: It work. Yeah its minor to the scale. I want to know y we have to extrude below and then scale

Comment: Because *Alt+S* didn't work well for the vertices'/edges' normals I decided to try it on the faces' normals. That's why I extruded edges to create them.

Comment: If *Alt+s* does not work for someone on Ubuntu, then you should know that this is an Ubuntu issue. I just tried it on macOS and it works perfectly, but not on my Ubuntu machine. Don't know why yet. That it worked on macOS shows at least, that I'm doing it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

The edges ***are*** scaling proportionally, they are just of different lengths.  For instance if the long edge is 6 units and the short edges are 2 units, when they are scaled by a factor of 1.5, the delta length of the long edge will be 3 units while the short edges will only be 1.

This might help you, though, (if I understand you correctly) in keeping the edges forward, even though the scaling remains the same.  I'm just adjusting the pivot point and using 3D cursor as the pivot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: from my view the top image is still not perfect. The side face is big to the center face is small.

Comment: @ateks - I wasn't implying that this was exactly what you wanted, I was just trying to offer an alternative.  The only point is that the edges are scaling properly.