# Extrude around selected vertices

Tags: extrude

I selected the outside vertices of the following mesh:

[image]

I would like to extrude these selected vertices to have exactly 3mm around them. 
I tried with E + S but I can't get exactly the same distance between the selected vertices and the new ones:
[image]

The normals:
[image]

[The blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47176)

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84358/how-to-scale-all-the-edges-proportionally

Comment: Thanks you for thé link but how can I set thé précise distance?

Comment: @Maxime Just input the desired value using keyboard.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'm really sorry but I can make it working. Could you show me a real example using my blend file? When I try ALT S, the mesh is modified on each axis (I just want x and y)

Comment: Press `Shift`+`Z` to scale only in X and Y during transforms.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos It's still not working. Maybe there is an issue due to the face normals. I added a screenshot in the initial message